# Javascript currency regular expression replace

Tags: javascript, regex, input, replace, currency

For my business web application I want a user to only be able to enter valid currency values in a textbox.

Currently I use

```
$input.val($input.val().replace(/[^.\d]/g, ''));
```

But this doesn't take in consideration order or multiple decimal seperators.

So the user either has to enter a whole integer or a valid decimal value e.g.:

- 49
- 49.50

Bonus points if this is allowed too:

- .50 (for 0.50)

So I don't want to validate, I want to restrict typing into the textbox. Is this possible with a single regexp replace?

Comment: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: I don't want to use any masking plugins for this. And yes, I do need safari support.

Comment: It's considered bad manners to mess with what the user is typing and much more friendly to just let users know if the value of the field doesn't meet validation requirements. Users might make mistakes, but they aren't brainless or incapable of entering a currency value correctly.

Comment: @RobG thank you for speaking up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this in two steps. Restrict the user to type only the number characters and `.` character.

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode < 31 && (charCode > 48 || charCode < 57))
    return true;
return false;
```

And the next one is for allowing the `.`:

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode == 46 && (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
    return true;
return false;
```

The next step will be not allowing double periods.

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode == 46 && (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
    if (charCode == 46 && value.indexOf(".") !== false)
        return true;
return false;
```

Hope you can have this as a starting point.

**Snippet**

Open Deal: Break it if you can.

```js
function check(inp) {
  var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  console.log(charCode);
  if (charCode == 8)
    return true;
  if ((charCode > 46 && charCode < 58) || (charCode > 95 && charCode < 106) || charCode == 110 || charCode == 190)
    if (charCode == 110 || charCode == 190)
      if (inp.value.indexOf(".") == -1)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    else
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="return check(this);" />
```

Comment: It's better to look at the actual character typed rather than the character code. Values can be entered without pressing any keys.

Comment: Yes. But we can disable Paste. @RobG

Comment: Why would you disable paste?

Comment: @maček—because removing user functionality is easier than programming for it. :-/

Comment: Guys, added a snippet. Break it if you can! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar—paste from context menu works fine, as does paste from tool bar and drag and drop, any value I like. Please add even more code.

Comment: @RobG, Wow... Didn't expect that. Then we need to restrict drag and drop too! Okay, so you guys restrict ... Well, I didn't restrict paste at all!

Answer (score 0):

It's more user friendly to advise of errors and let users fix them themselves. You might consider using the keyup event, but showing an error too early (before the user has had a chance to enter a valid value) can be annoying too. e.g.

```js
function validate(el) {
  var type = el.className;
  var errEl = document.getElementById(el.name + 'Err');
  if (type == 'typeCurrency') {
    var currencyRe = /^-?(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$/;
    errEl.style.visibility = currencyRe.test(el.value)? 'hidden' : 'visible';
  }
}
```

```css
  .errorMessage {
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
Cost&nbsp;<input onblur="validate(this)" name="foo" class="typeCurrency" placeholder="0.00"><br>
<span id="fooErr" class="errorMessage">Please enter a valid cost, e.g. 2.45</span>
```